# [SmartIrc4Net]: UI Freezing

Tags: multithreading

So I've run into an issue while creating a 'Bot' to watch over one of my IRC Channels, and once the Listen() command is sent the UI is prone to freezing... Now I'm aware that this may be caused by SmartIrc4Net constantly checking for data and what not...

So I've been trying to implement it into another thread by using three of the following ways... But once I start to debug the program no 'debug' message is sent to the server, I know for a fact that the 'Bot' is connecting successfully and this is only when a new 'Thread' is not introduced to the application.

All my 'Bot' programming is separated into Class Library's, and I have tried putting it all into a 'DEBUG' application, and it yields that same annoying result.

My mind is beyong boggled and hopefully someone here has assist me with my situation, as fast as humanly possible....

(Notice: Expect responses from 13:00 / 15:30 to 24:00 GMT)

```
new Thread(() =>
{
   while(BotConnection._IsBotConnected)
   {
      BotConnection.IRCBOT.Listen();
   }
});
-- AND --
ThreadStart IRCThread = new ThreadStart(_IRCListen);
private static void _IRCListen()
{
    BotConnection.IRCBOT.Listen();
}
-- AND --
ThreadStart ListenThread = delegate
{
    BotConnection.IRCBOT.Listen();
}; new Thread(ListenThread).Start();
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up fixing the problem by doing the following.

```
        ThreadStart ListenThread = delegate
        {
            while(BotConnection._IsBotConnected)
            {
                BotConnection.IRCBOT.Listen();
                BotConnection.IRCBOT.RfcPing("IRC_URL_CON");
            }

        }; new Thread(ListenThread).Start();
```